# Calling a query from RIA Services with entities that have children created by other methods

Tags: linq, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have this bit of code that does not work because Entity Framework doesn't recognize the `CreateItemDC` method.  `CreateItemDC` is a modular private method that creates a data contract for the given `Item` entity.  I use `CreateItemDC` all throughout my service whenever I need to return an Item data contract, but I can't use it here.  I can realize the sequence of `ProjectItems` into an array or enumerable because I would have to do this to all `ProjectItem` entities in my database as the query criteria is specified on the client and I don't have access to it here.  Do I have any better options here?  It seems that RIA Services is not worth the trouble.  I'm really wishing I had used plain WCF with this project.

```
    [Query]
    public IQueryable<ProjectItemDC> GetProjectItems()
    {
        return from projectItem in ObjectContext.ProjectItems
               select new ProjectItemDC
               {
                   ID = projectItem.ID,
                   LibraryItem = CreateItemDC(projectItem.LibraryItem),
                   LibraryItemID = projectItem.LibraryItemID,
                   ProjectID = projectItem.ProjectID,
                   Quantity = projectItem.Quantity,
                   Width = projectItem.Width,
                   Height = projectItem.Height,
                   Depth = projectItem.Depth,
                   SheetMaterialID = projectItem.SheetMaterialID,
                   BandingMaterialID = projectItem.BandingMaterialID,
                   MaterialVolume = projectItem.MaterialVolume,
                   MaterialWeight = projectItem.MaterialWeight
               };
    }
```

P.S.  I do love LINQ and E.F. though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `ToArray()` against `ObjectContext.ProjectItems` to force EF to load all the items, however, your query will no longer be composable on the client.

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<ProjectItemDC> GetProjectItems()
{
    return from projectItem in ObjectContext.ProjectItems.ToArray()
           select new ProjectItemDC
           {
               ID = projectItem.ID,
               LibraryItem = CreateItemDC(projectItem.LibraryItem),
               LibraryItemID = projectItem.LibraryItemID,
               ProjectID = projectItem.ProjectID,
               Quantity = projectItem.Quantity,
               Width = projectItem.Width,
               Height = projectItem.Height,
               Depth = projectItem.Depth,
               SheetMaterialID = projectItem.SheetMaterialID,
               BandingMaterialID = projectItem.BandingMaterialID,
               MaterialVolume = projectItem.MaterialVolume,
               MaterialWeight = projectItem.MaterialWeight
           };
}
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in your comment, it gets all of the data out of the database at once which is not ideal. In order to create the `LibraryItem` with your private method, you cannot compose the query on the client. Instead, you should filter within the query method and then create the array.

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<ProjectItemDC> GetProjectItems(int id, string filter, object blah)
{
    var projectItems = ObjectContext.ProjectItems.Where(...).ToArray();
    return projectItems.Select(projectItem => new ProjectItemDC{...};
}
```

Comment: This would create an array in memory of every `ProjectItem` entity in the database.  Which is not an option.

Comment: Unless you are composing the query on the client, you are already pulling all the data out.

Comment: Which is what I ended up doing. My next project will use WCF. I guess if you are doing straight CRUD RIA Services makes sense, but I've hit so many brick walls in the last year or so that I myself am done with it.  I do like composing queries on the client, but there are just too many limitations otherwise.

Comment: WCF RIA is very opinionated. I agree WCF is the correct solution when the way you want or need to implement offends WCF RIA's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to go with plain WCF, you can, no problem, just change the code to

```
[Query(IsComposable=false)]
public IEnumerable<ProjectItemDC> GetProjectItems(string myParm1, string myParm2) 
    { 
        return from projectItem in ObjectContext.ProjectItems 
               select new ProjectItemDC 
               { 
                   ID = projectItem.ID, 
                   LibraryItem = CreateItemDC(projectItem.LibraryItem), 
                   LibraryItemID = projectItem.LibraryItemID, 
                   ProjectID = projectItem.ProjectID, 
                   Quantity = projectItem.Quantity, 
                   Width = projectItem.Width, 
                   Height = projectItem.Height, 
                   Depth = projectItem.Depth, 
                   SheetMaterialID = projectItem.SheetMaterialID, 
                   BandingMaterialID = projectItem.BandingMaterialID, 
                   MaterialVolume = projectItem.MaterialVolume, 
                   MaterialWeight = projectItem.MaterialWeight 
               }.ToArray(); 
    }
```

write your own filtering/sorting logic and you're done.
Yes, you've lost WCF Ria Services dynamic query capabilities, but this is pretty much what you get with plain old WCF, isnt'it ?

If you instead need WCF Ria dynamic sorting/filtering/grouping you must take some additional steps, involving the visit of the Expression that WCF Ria Services create for you.

HTH

Comment: How does one get the Expression?

Comment: override the Query method of your DomainService class, if the client has specified an expression the proprty Query of parameter queryDescription is valorized. So you can grab the queryDescription.Query.Expression